# DIY PHP shortcode with preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

I understand that preg_replace_callback is ideal for this purpose, but I'm not sure how to finish what I've started.

You can see what I'm trying to achieve - I'm just not sure how to use the callback function:

```
//my string
$string  = 'Dear [attendee], we are looking forward to seeing you on [day]. Regards, [staff name]. ';

//search pattern
$pattern = '~\[(.*?)\]~';

//the function call
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callback', $string);

//the callback function
function callback ($matches) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "</pre>";

    //pseudocode
    if shortcode = "attendee" then "Warren"
    if shortcode = "day" then "Monday"
    if shortcode = "staff name" then "John"

    return ????;
}

echo $result;
```

The desired output would be `Dear Warren, we are looking forward to seeing you on Monday. Regards, John.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function *preg_replace_callback* provides an array in the 1st parameter ($matches).
In your case, *$matches[0]* contains the entire matched string, while **$matches[1]** contains the 1st matching group (i.e. the name of the variable to replace).
The callback function **should return the variable value** corresponding to the matching string (i.e. the variable name in brackets).

So you could try this:

```
<?php

//my string
$string  = 'Dear [attendee], we are looking forward to seeing you on [day]. Regards, [staff name]. ';

// Prepare the data
$data = array(
    'attendee'=>'Warren',
    'day'=>'Monday',
    'staff name'=>'John'
);

//search pattern
$pattern = '~\[(.*?)\]~';

//the function call
$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'callback', $string);

//the callback function
function callback ($matches) {
    global $data;

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($matches);
    echo "\n</pre>";

    // If there is an entry for the variable name return its value
    // else return the pattern itself
    return isset($data[$matches[1]]) ? $data[$matches[1]] : $matches[0];

}

echo $result;
?>
```

This will give...

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => [attendee]
>       [1] => attendee
>   )
>   Array
>   (
>       [0] => [day]
>       [1] => day
>   )
>   Array
>   (
>       [0] => [staff name]
>       [1] => staff name
>   )
>   
>   Dear Warren, we are looking forward to seeing you on Monday. Regards, John.